# What is the process of aging exactly?

Tags: human-biology, evolution

### Getting old

Hello community, I have been thinking about age, and I thought that [aging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negligible_senescence) is the *reverse of how a biological system is able to fix itself* over time. Actually, some species actually are able to reverse it completely, such as the [jellyfish and lobsters](https://www.rd.com/list/animals-that-live-forever/) for up to [400 years in the Greenland sharks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negligible_senescence). Moreover, by evolution principle, those species must've exchanged this ability over others, which is noticeable considering they're really adapted to their habitats.

### What does research tell us on aging so far?

> According to [Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/science/human-aging/Digestive-system), aging affects many dimensions for all humans.

So, when scientists are talking about "a cure to aging", I cannot comprehend whether they're proving that those are **symptoms of some biological factor** (such as producing a certain gene, etc.) or whether all of them **share the likelihood to appear more often** over a certain age?

> *How can studying those species help science advance in research?*

Comment: this is an **awfully** broad question. Can you start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ageing#Biological_basis and narrow down your question?